# Jquery how to find element from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to find an element which is outside from element which I'm trying click.

I need to click #form-1 and slideToggle .business-form-kaufen.
You can look hierarchy in the picture.

Thanks for help!

[image: Here is a picture]

Comment: Please don't use pictures to show code. Show the code as text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go up two DIV levels from the button, then go to the next DIV, and find `.business-form-kaufen` in there.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".business-form-kaufen").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent()` relatively

```js
$("#form-1").on("click", function(evt) {
  $(this).parent().parent().next().find(".business-form-kaufen").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.business-form-kaufen {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 text-left">
  <div id="kaufen-form-submit">
    <a id="form-1">Unverbindliches ...</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wpcf7-fp09-p448-ol">
  <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
  <form>
    <div class="business-form-kaufen">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Or if you can either edit your html to add some `id` to the `.business-form-kaufen` or be sure that it is only this single element of this class, you can do it much simpler:

```js
$("#form-1").on("click", function(evt) {
  $(".business-form-kaufen").slideToggle();
  // $("#business-form-kaufen").slideToggle() uncomment if you can setup unique id on this element
});
```

```css
.business-form-kaufen {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 text-left">
  <div id="kaufen-form-submit">
    <a id="form-1">Unverbindliches ...</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wpcf7-fp09-p448-ol">
  <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
  <form>
    <div class="business-form-kaufen">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `form` and `business-form-kaufen` are 1 to 1 relationship? I'd put them together in a container and use `parents()` to find the container and then `find()` to look for the `business-form-kaufen`.

This way, the code is smart enough to look for the `business-form-kaufen` without the need to hard code the DOM structure.

Comment: You do see where the element `business-form-kaufen` is in the DOM? closest only traverses up the DOM